# Please how do i collapse any open section of the accordion when I click on another

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please how do i collapse any open section of the accordion when I click on another? When a section is clicked, it remains open after clicking another section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
    display: block;
}
div.panel.collapse {
    display: block;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");            
  }
}
</script>
```

Please how do i collapse any open section of the accordion when I click on another? When a section is clicked, it remains open after clicking another section.

Comment: check out my answer mate if that is what you want done

Comment: You could implement it using radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

I have done a fiddle for you maybe you could check this out I have used jquery on this one is this something you want done?

```
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
   $(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).next().removeClass('show');
 }else{
    $('.accordion').removeClass('active')
  $('.panel').removeClass('show')
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).next().addClass('show');
}
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ktdsnnkp/1/

Comment: Thanks Rani.  when I combine the html, css and jquery codes, the accordion couldn't be opened or collapsed. The accordion was not responsive when clicked

Comment: Rani, I exported the code above from fiddle, but it doesn't respond to clicks when I run it

Comment: hey mate I just got home @Emmanuel you need to have a jquery runinng page mate do you have it?